# Использование функции xpos \ есть ошибки

Tags: delphi

**Прежде чем задать вопрос:** Сделала тест данной функции.

**Сама функция:**

```
function XPos( const cSubStr, cString :string ) :integer;
var
  nLen0, nLen1, nCnt, nCnt2 :integer;
  cFirst :Char;
begin
  nLen0 := Length(cSubStr);
  nLen1 := Length(cString);

  if nLen0 > nLen1 then
    begin
      // the substr is longer than the cString
      result := 0;
    end

  else if nLen0 = 0 then
    begin
      // null substr not allowed
      result := 0;
    end

  else

    begin

      // the outer loop finds the first matching character....
      cFirst := UpCase( cSubStr[1] );
      result := 0;

      for nCnt := 1 to nLen1 - nLen0 + 1 do
        begin

          if UpCase( cString[nCnt] ) = cFirst then
            begin
              // this might be the start of the substring...at least the first
              // character matches....
              result := nCnt;

              for nCnt2 := 2 to nLen0 do
                begin

                  if UpCase( cString[nCnt + nCnt2 - 1] ) <> UpCase( cSubStr[nCnt2] ) then
                    begin
                      // failed
                      result := 0;
                      break;
                    end;

                end;

            end;


          if result > 0 then
            break;
        end;


    end;
end;
```

**Ну и подключение функции:**

```
   if (XPos('test', s) > 0)
   or(XPos('тест', s) > 0)
   then
  writeln(f1, S);
   end;
```

**К примеру, если в текстовом файле - есть текст:**

```
Test1
Тест2
test1
тест2
Test1
Тест2
test1
тест2
11111
22222
```

**То на выходе я получаю текст:**

```
Test1
test1
тест2
Test1
test1
тест2
```

**А должно быть:**

```
Test1
Тест2
test1
тест2
Test1
Тест2
test1
тест2
```

**Вопрос:** Получается результат меньше на две строчки, **в чем может быть проблема ?**

Comment: - в `UpCase` для кириллицы. Не работает сравнение `'Тест'` с `'тест'`.

Comment: Или буквы `е` - из разных алфавитов.

Comment: @Igor, Буквы правильные проверила.  Я так поняла что нужно прописать AnsiUpperCase место Uper но тогда пишет ошибку. Если это так, то как правильно исправить функцию - что бы русские и английские воспринимала?

Comment: А если использовать функцию `System.StrUtils.AnsiContainsText` вместо всего этого?

Comment: @MBo, А как будет выглядеть сама функция AnsiContainsText? Или я что то путаю, подскажите ?

Comment: Это готовая функция из модуля StrUtils - её можно использовать для проверки вхождения подстроки. Она не даёт позицию - но Вам это и не требуется.

Comment: @MBo, Это будет так для для проверки вхождения подстроки -  AnsiContainsText(s). Или?

Comment: А Вы посмотрели во встроенном или онлайн-хелпе?

Comment: @MBo, Да, но почему то не могу разобраться...

Comment: Сколько там аргументов и что они означают?

Comment: @MBo, буду сейчас разбираться, Пробовала делать вот так AnsiContainsText('test', s); Но знаю что глупость делаю, получается копируется весь текст.

Comment: Вдумайтесь в названия параметров.

Comment: @MBo, Только что разобралась. Получилось. Но вот один минус, скорость не радует. В  функции, что выше - скорость лучше...